# How to select Max StartDate in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to only get out the max StartDate, its multiples of dates with the same CustomNumber

Any suggestions?

My simplified code

```
from Cus in Customers
where Cus.CustomNumber == 2 
group Cus by new 
 { Cus.Name,Cus.City,Cus.StartDate}
 into grp
 select new 
 {
    Name = grp.Key.Name,
    City = grp.Key.City, 
    StartDate = grp.Key.StartDate,

    //I have tried, but it doesnt work for me
    //StartDate = grp.Max(Cus=> grp.Key.StartDate)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

```
var result = from Cus in Customers
             where Cus.CustomNumber == 2 
             group Cus by new 
             { Cus.Name, Cus.StartDate}
             into grp
             select new 
             {
                 Name = grp.Key.Name,
                 StartDate = grp.Max(x=>x.StartDate)
             };
```

Using `grp` you have access to the random group you create in your linq query, then using the extension method called `Max` you get the maximum `StartDate` in your group.

**UPDATE**

Since now you have a join before the grouping, you have to change your code to the following one:

```
var result = from res in 
             (from customer in Customers
             join house in Houses 
             on customer.CustomNumber equals house.CustomNumber
             where customer.CustomNumber == 2               
             select new { Name = customer.Name, StartDate = house.StartDate })
             group res by res.Name into grp
             select new { Name = grp.Key, StartDate = grp.Max(x=>x.StartDate) };
```

**UPDATE #2**

If you want you get both the customer's Name and City in your result, you have to use the following code:

```
var result = from res in 
             (from customer in Customers
             join house in Houses 
             on customer.CustomNumber equals house.CustomNumber
             where customer.CustomNumber == 2               
             select new { Name = customer.Name, City = customer.Name, StartDate = house.StartDate })
             group res by new { res.Name, res.City } into grp
             select new 
             { 
                 Name = grp.Key.Name, 
                 City = grp.Key.City,  
                 StartDate = grp.Max(x=>x.StartDate) 
             };
```

Comment: It works in this example, thanks! But I have 2 different tables in my real code and the it doesnt work. I have changed the orginal questions. Any suggestions how to get it to work?

Comment: @user3635120 ok, give me a few minutes to check it out and I would let you know.

Comment: It doesnt work for me, maybe I need to publish the whole code!

Comment: I got this message(I use LinqPad4)

`Cannot execute text selection: 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'StartDate' and no extension method 'StartDate' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)`

Comment: Ok, please let me check it out and i will make the corresponding changes later. Thank you for being patient.

Comment: It works :)
But if have both Name and City, and I want to get out both, how do I do that?
I have updated my code with City also!

Comment: @user3635120 ok, I will check it out and I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: @user3635120 please check my update and let me know if it meets your requirements

Comment: @user3635120 Thank you. I am glad that I could help.

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
StartDate = grp.Max(x => x.StartDate)
```